# How to use Apache Solr as data source for a view

Tags: views, 7, search

Is it possible to use data indexed in Solr as the data source for a specific view?
I already tried installing the search api, search api page, entity api, ctools, search api solr and the views api.

I already created a server and an index which uses solr:

[image]

But the only fields that I get are node fields:

[image]

I'm expecting to get the fields from documents that I indexed in Solr. How do I do that in Drupal, is there a specific module that would allow me to make use of the fields that already exists in Solr as the fields for a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is [Apache Solr Views module](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views).

> This module provides Views implementation for the [Apache Solr Search
>   Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) Project 7.x-1.x branch. Requires Views 3.
>
> This module will provide facet navigation combined with searching to
>   make a powerful user experience.

After installing this module, you can able to create a Apache Solr view, which list all the fields which are available in the indexed documents in the solr.